# Pygame walk towards rotation

Tags: python, pygame, geometry, rotation, degrees

i'm trying to make a circle go towards the way its looking, when i put 0 it goes towards 0 but when i put 90 for some reason it goes towards like 200 or something

```
import pygame
import math
import random
from random import randint

pygame.init()



screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
""""""


def rad_to_offset(radians, offset): 
    x = math.cos(radians) * offset
    y = math.sin(radians) * offset
    return [x, y]


X = 250
Y = 250

""""""
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False

     """ if i put 90 it doesnt go towards 90 """
     xy = rad_to_offset(90, 1)
     X += xy[0]
     Y += xy[1]
     print(X, Y)
     screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

     pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (X, Y), 20)

     pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The unit of the angle in the trigonometric functions is [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) but not [Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)). Use [`math.radians`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians) to convert from degrees to radians:

```py
def rad_to_offset(degrees, offset): 
    x = math.cos(math.radians(degrees)) * offset
    y = math.sin(math.radians(degrees)) * offset
    return [x, y]
```